# Is (Z,+,0,1,P2,P3) decidable?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, decidability, theories-of-arithmetic

Is Presburger arithmetic, augmented with two unary predicates P2, P3, for powers of 2 and powers of 3 respectively, decidable? 
I know that adding just one of P2, P3 to Presburger keeps it decidable, and I'm asking about both. 
If I understood correctly the table in the end of http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~point/papiers/Pres.pdf, it is unknown. Is this truly unknown?

Comment: A small comment. *Presburger arithmetic* usually means $(\mathbb{Z},+,<)$ (or $(\mathbb{N},+)$ depending on taste). So the structure described in the question is $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,P_2,P_3)$, which is not the same as $(\mathbb{Z},+,P_2,P_3)$ in the table in Point's paper.

Comment: As an example of the difficulty, try deciding the sentence $\forall x(P2(x) \wedge P3(x+1) \rightarrow x<9)$. It was only settled by Mihailescu in 2002.

Comment: This does follow from the Catalan conjectureu, but it turns out to have been known much earlier, see for example https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/catalan.pdf. But it is certainly true that the theory of $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,2^\mathbb{N},3^\mathbb{N})$ contains difficult number theory.

Answer (score 16):

Christian Schulz (a grad student at Urbana) and Philipp Hieronymi have recently shown that $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,2^{\mathbb{N}},3^{\mathbb{N}})$ is undecidable. And I believe they prove this for $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,m^{\mathbb{N}},n^{\mathbb{N}})$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\log_m n$ irrational. The paper isn't out yet but the result has been presented in talks (for example, [SIU Pure Mathematics Conference](https://math.siu.edu/llmc2019/Logic2019-abstracts.pdf#page=11) in May 2019).

**Edit:** I am going to add an explanation of one reason why this result is interesting.

Let $m,n$ be natural numbers $\ge 2$. A subset $X$ of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ is $n$-recognizable if the set of $n$-ary expansions of elements of $X$ is recognized by some finite automaton. For example $n^\mathbb{N}$ is $n$-recognizable, the set of odious numbers (numbers with an odd number of $1$'s in their binary expansion) is $2$-recognizable. The Cobham–Semanov theorem states that if $m,n$ are multiplicatively independent and $X$ is both $m$- and $n$-recognizable then $X$ is definable $(\mathbb{Z},+,<)$. So in particular if $k = 1$ then $X$ is a finite union of arithmetic progressions.

There is a connection to logic. Let $V_n$ be the ternary predicate on $\mathbb{Z}$ where $V_n(d,j,l)$ holds if $d$ is the $j$th $n$-ary digit of $l$. Then $X$ is $n$-recognizable iff $X$ is definable in $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,V_n)$. This is used to show that $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,V_n)$ is decidable. (And in fact decidability of these structures has had notable mathematical applications, see for example the paper Madhusudan–Nowotka–Rajasekaran–Shallit, *Lagrange’s Theorem for Binary Squares*, MFCS 2018, doi:[10.4230/LIPIcs.MFCS.2018.18](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.MFCS.2018.18), arXiv:[1710.04247](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04247).)

Villemaire showed that $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,V_n,V_m)$ is undecidable when $m,n$ are multiplicatively independent. Bes showed that if $X$ is definable in $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,V_n)$ and not definable in $(\mathbb{Z},+,<)$ then $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,X)$ defines $n^\mathbb{N}$. So putting it together we see that if $m,n$ are multiplicatively independent, $X$ is $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,V_n)$-definable, $Y \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^l$ is $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,V_m)$-definable, and neither $X$ nor $Y$ is definable in $(\mathbb{Z},+,<)$, then $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,X,Y)$ is undecidable. This is a mutual generalization of Cobham–Semenov and Villemaire's result.

It should be noted that $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,n^\mathbb{N})$ does not define $V_n$. In fact these two structures are separated by a deep dividing line, $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,n^{\mathbb{N}})$ is NIP and $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,V_n)$ is as IP as you can get.

Comment: Do you have any reference whatsoever for this? At the very least something like an abstract of a talk which claims that?

Comment: https://192.17.3.249/cal?year=2019&month=10&day=01&interval=year&advance=1+month&move=Advance&interval=year&regexp=Model+Theory+and+Descriptive+Set+Theory+Seminar It was on March 15 2019. (I went to the talk).

Comment: Here's a pdf with a (short) abstract on page 11: https://math.siu.edu/llmc2019/Logic2019-abstracts.pdf (I was also at the talk, for what it's worth.) Erik, my understanding is that is is joint with Philipp?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I forgot about that. I will edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do they show it by showing that it defines multiplication?

Comment: @JamesHanson The proof does not yield definibility of multiplication, and last time I talked to them they thought that multiplication might not be definable. They uniformly interpret $([0,n],+,\times,<)$ where $+$ and $\times$ are considered as partial functions. All of this happens on a sparse set.

Comment: I note the talk mentions $\mathbb{N}$, but you say $\mathbb{Z}$. I presume this doesn't matter?

Comment: @DavidRoberts $(\mathbb{Z},+,<)$ and $(\mathbb{N},+)$ are bi-interpretable. People studying "expansions of Presburger" will often pick and choose between the two.

Comment: In fact the interpretation of $(\mathbb{Z},+,<)$ in $(\mathbb{N},+)$ is exactly the usual construction of integers from natural numbers, i,e. $(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})/\approx$ where $(m,m') \approx (n,n')$ iff $m + n' = n + m'$.

Comment: @ErikWalsberg, I think the summary of your addendum is: "This means that $P_2$ and $P_3$ follow the same pattern as $V_2$ and $V_3$, where adding one of them to Presburger arithmetic retains decidability and adding both removes decidability. It is interesting to see so much parallelism, given that the expansions by $P_2$ or $P_3$ are NIP, and the expansions by $V_2$ or $V_3$ are IP." But if that is the right summary, the results by Bes and their consequences seem a bit far afield -- or perhaps you are seeing an additional connection that I am not.

Comment: I wanted to emphasize that undecidability of $(\mathbb{Z},+,<,2^\mathbb{N},3^\mathbb{N})$ remains true when $2^\mathbb{N}$,$3^\mathbb{N}$ are replaced by any non-Presburger definable $2$-,$3$-recognizable sets, respectively. Presburger definable sets are just given by finitely many $\mathbb{Q}$-linear and congruence conditions, but recognizable sets can be more complicated.

Comment: Very nice result. Do they also mention the case without the order?

Comment: The case without order is very different. I don't think decidability is known but $(\mathbb{Z},+,2^{\mathbb{N}},3^{\mathbb{N}})$ is model-theoretically tame, in particular superstable. This is due to Gabe, see Theorem 3.16 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00105.pdf. $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z},+,<)$ lie on opposite sides of the deep model-theoretic dividing line of stability, so their expansions are very different.

Comment: @GabeConant is anything known about decidability here? Your result seems to use a Mordell-Lang type result, so I would guess that decidability would require an effective version of that result, which might not be known (???)

Comment: As far as I know, decidability of $(\mathbb{Z},+,2^{\mathbb{N}},3^{\mathbb{N}})$ is not known. My proof of stability is for $(\mathbb{Z},+,Q)$, where $Q$ is the set of naturals divisible only by $2$ and $3$. Then stability descends to the first structure since it's a reduct. The number-theoretic result I use is Theorem 1.1 of [arXiv0409604](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409604.pdf), which gives effective bounds. But I don't often think about decidability so I don't know if it's the "right" kind of effective.

Comment: The proof of stability for $(\mathbb{Z},+,Q)$ goes by proving stability of the induced structure on $Q$, and then applying a general result of Casanovas-Ziegler. So I don't prove a QE statement for instance. But it doesn't seem unreasonable that this structure could be decidable.

Comment: The question of whether $(\mathbb{Z},+,(n^\mathbb{N})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} )$ is decidable does seem interesting. The Catalan conjecture is equivalent to natural infinite family of sentences. I wonder if any open problems are equivalent to a single sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that does seem to be what the paper is claiming. The author seems to be an expert, so there seems to be little reason to doubt the question is open. :)

Comment: Thanks Bjorn! I just want to make sure, it seems like a very classical question, so I'm not sure.

Comment: It's classical but it's fairly specific... that structure with the sets $P_2$ and $P_3$ is not the most natural, right?

Comment: it's not natural before you know you can either one of them :)